# Floor function equivalence relation and partition

Tags: equivalence-relations, ceiling-and-floor-functions, set-partition

Could someone help me with this question? I would like to know if I did it right.

Define the relation ∼ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that x ∼ y if and only if ⌊2x⌋ = ⌊2y⌋.

**1) Prove that ∼ is an equivalent relation.**
Take x,y,z ∈ R.
I have the symmetry and reflexivity part, but I´m not sure about the  transitivity:

take x ∼ y and y ∼ z, then ⌊2x⌋ = ⌊2y⌋ and ⌊2y⌋ = ⌊2z⌋. It's trivial that ⌊2x⌋ = ⌊2z⌋ and x ∼ z, so the function is transitive?

**2) The equivalence classes give a partition of R. Describe the partition.**

The partition is ( [i, i + 1/2): i ∈ Z ) of $\mathbb{R}$?

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Everything is fine.

Comment: The function is not transitive. The **relation** is transitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point 1 is ok.

About point 2: I would say that the partition is something like
$$
\mathcal{P}=\{A_k: k\in \mathbb{Z}\},
$$
being $A_k=[k,k+\frac{1}{2})$.

Basically is what you have written, but you have to improve the notation. A partition is a set of subsets.